# how to use $scope.$watchCollection insted of angular.forEach()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have this block of code when user do delete or undelete it will update deleted property on model. my problem I'm using for angular.forEach() just want to see if it possible to change  angular.forEach to use  $scope.$watchCollection() ?

```
    $scope.deleteForm = function (form) {
        var result = confirm('Want to delete the form ?');
        if (result){
            var splitDeleteHref = form.deleteHref.split('/');
            var formName = splitDeleteHref[1];
            var formId = splitDeleteHref[2];
            homeService.deleteForm(formName, formId);
                $scope.$watchCollection('forms',)
            //angular.forEach($scope.forms, function(value, key) {
            //    if (value.recordId === form.recordId) {
            //        $scope.forms[key].deleted = true;
            //    }
            //});
        }
    };

    $scope.undeleteForm = function (form) {
        var result = confirm('Want to undelete the form ?');
        if (result) {
            homeService.undeleteForm(form).then(function () {
                //angular.forEach($scope.forms, function (value, key) {
                //    if (value.recordId === form.recordId) {
                //        $scope.forms[key].deleted = false;
                //    }
                //});
            });

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.$watch` and `.$watchCollection` are for watching for changes to an object or a collection of objects. These methods cannot be used to iterate over an array, which is what `angular.forEach` is for. Your usage of `.forEach` appears to be correct, so I recommend leaving it as is.